# how to notify waiting main thread from user thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, wait

```java
class A implements Runnable
{
  public void run()
  {
    try
    {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch(Exception e){};
    notify();//This has to wake up the sleeping main thread.
  }
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    A a=new A();
    Thread t=new Thread(a);
    t.start();
    try
    {
      Thread.wait(5000);
    }
    catch(Exception e){};
    System.out.println("Rest of the code");
  }
}
```

When I compile this code, JVM says non-static method wait can't be referenced from static main method.

When I put that in a different method then it shows illegal monitor exception.

Please suggest me a way to solve this problem. Don't suggest something like join. Because i have to do it with wait and notify alone.

Comment: Ever heard of indentation? Your code could use some... As is, it's not very readable.

Comment: I wasted half an hour trying to use notify and wait.  If I couldn't use join, I'd write my own code to wait on the thread,. That way, I know it will wait properly.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things:

- wait method belong to Object and not thread.
- wait method is not a static method and hence you can't use `ClassName.wait`
- For wait to work, you need to obtain object's monitor before and if you don't you get IllegalMonitorException.

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) for details about wait api.

Comment: since object calss is a super class for all classes can't  i make use of it to achieve this??? if so how could i do that??

Comment: Yes you could but unlike sleep, wait is not a static method and hence you need to instantiate Object like `Object obj = new Object(); synchronized(obj) {obj.wait(1111);....}`